# Similar behavior to joining two fields Odoo13, it's possible?

Tags: odoo, odoo-13, odoo-view

I have two fields: language and level, I need to implement a behavior similar to the one in the attached image, where when choosing the language and its level they are added at the bottom as a label and the record is saved in the database, language -level. I thank you all.
[image: case]

Comment: You can use a `Many2many` field with `many2many_tags` widget

Comment: thnks, i´ll try, the Many2many field must be a concatenation of the language and level fields